# How to view console messages from specific js files in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, devtools

I have two js files that interact with each other and I only need to see errors and logs from those two js files while debugging. Everything else is distracting.
In chrome, I can right click on the script file names in the console log and click "hide messages from x.js", but firefox doesn't seem to have that.

Also, using the negative sign only works on one word.

Lastly, In the filter bar. Regex doesn't seem to work for excluding words. Only including.

What is the best solution for only seeing messages from the files I want?

Answer (score 1):

You can also filter out errors in the Firefox console using the filter box (above the console), *[using regular expressions](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/devtools-user/web_console/console_messages/index.html#filtering-with-regular-expressions)*.

---

So, say we have two words(`InvalidWord`, `SomeInvalidWord`) logged in the console that needs exclusion from the console, we can use a regex which first matches them i.e. `/InvalidWord|SomeInvalidWord/` and then negate them using minus (`-`).

**SAMPLE OUTPUT:**

[image: sample-output]

Comment: I mentioned that. It doesn't seem to work for negating multiple script files. i.e excluding multiple words rather than including them.

Comment: Just make a console log with 3 different words and then try to exclude 2 of them from showing up using regex

Comment: So janky. Good find

Comment: @John From the docs which I added the link to.